# How many fixed points does this function have?

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems

The function is $f :\overline{\Bbb R}\to \overline{\Bbb R}, x \mapsto x^5$.

Moreover we know that $\overline{\Bbb R}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ is a compact set. So does it have $3$ or $5$ fixed points ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does $\overline{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$?

Comment: it doesn't matter because the closer of $\mathbb R$ is not compact.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes it is

Comment: @JonesY for me $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is compact

Comment: It depends on the topology applied. Often, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the [two point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28mathematics%29#An_example), in which case, it is compact.

Comment: @robjohn so by fixed points theorem there are 5 fixed points ?

Comment: Voting to close for profanity.

Comment: @Did, I just edited it out, since nothing was added to the question.

Comment: @ Did, for profanity (!) you wrote; go to see an American movie; you will be edified.

Comment: @Did Why it should be ?

Comment: Which fixed point theorem are you thinking of? Remember that while $\overline{\mathbb R} is compact it's not algebraically closed.

Comment: @Henrik I was thinking about the Brouwer's one in 1d

Comment: @loupblanc Huh? And this is related to the present case because?

Comment: @ Did , you lose the memory... You were shocked by the expression "fckn compact set". It is true that, If she had read, then Mother Theresa would have risked a heart attack!!

Comment: @loupblanc No loss of memory. Offtopic thread. Please pass on.

Comment: @Did sorry it was rage hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $\overline{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R \cup \{-\infty \}\cup \{+\infty\}, f(-\infty)=-\infty, f(+\infty)=+\infty$ it certainly has five fixed points.  You can exhibit them:  $-\infty,-1,0,1,+\infty$.  Once you define your terms carefully, the question has a clear answer.

Comment: But in $\overline{\Bbb R}$ we cannot define $\infty-\infty$ for instance.

Comment: @Maman:  we don't have to.  A fixed point is defined as a value $x$ where $f(x)=x$.  For the function definition I gave, that is true at all five points shown.

Comment: Ok so the final answer is $5$